# Bootstrap 4 Beta - Carousel with only text & caption text vertical align middle

Tags: bootstrap-4

I was wondering how to go about new BootStrap Carousel but with only text & caption text vertical align middle?

Any idea how to do it? Every time I remove 'img' from carousel - slides disappear.

I love new Bootstrap but It's difficult to figure stuff out.

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-50" src="" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Boyd W.</h3>
        <p>TEXT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-50" src="" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Diane L</h3>
        <p>TEXT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-50" src="" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Randall L</h3>
        <p>TEXT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-50" src="" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>John D.</h3>
        <p>TEXT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-50" src="" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Jody B.</h3>
        <p>TEXT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be better if you could place your code snippet here , so that every one could know what you have already done.

Comment: sure thing will do

Answer (score 2):

You need to give carousel-inner a height.

```
.carousel-inner{
  height: 100px;
}
.carousel-caption{
  top: 50%;
}
```

Here's a working codepen:

https://codepen.io/Washable/pen/Oxqjbq?editors=1100

Comment: Thanks Bro. That's awesome.

Comment: Next question is how to align caption text to vertical middle?